# python openpyxl Bold only input strings in statements that contain input strings

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to bold only input strings in statements that contain input strings.
please check my codes!

```
import openpyxl
import os
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from os import chdir
chdir('/Users/users/Desktop')
excel = openpyxl.load_workbook('1.xlsx')

sheet = excel.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')
A = sheet['A1' : 'A100']
word = input('input your string : ')
for col in A:
    for cell in col:
        cv = cell.value
        if word in cv:
            cv.font = word.Font(bold=True)
            print(cv.font)
```

### And I got this error.

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        14         cv = cell.value
>        15         if word in cv:
>   ---> 16             cv.font = word.Font(bold=True)
>        17             print(cv.font)
>        18
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Font'

How can I do this task..?

Comment: I think the font is applied to the cell and not the value. Try doing cell.font = Font(bold=True) instead and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to apply the font you don't need the 'word'.

```
cv.font = word.Font(bold=True)
```

Do it like this:

```
cell.font = Font(bold=True)
```

You have to apply the font to the excel element and not to your string.
For more information: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html